# reading and parsing a file, assigning each piece of the parsed string to its own variable

Tags: c++, parsing

```
 89   int Student::loadStudents() {
 90   Student newStudent;
 91   string comma;
 92   string line;
 93   ifstream myfile("student.dat");
 94   string name,email="";
 95   string status="";
 96   int id;
 97   if (myfile.is_open()){
 98     while ( getline (myfile,line) ) {
 99         //parse line
100         string myText(line);
101         istringstream iss(myText);
102         if(!(iss>>id)) id=0;
103
104         std::ignore(1,',');
105         std::getline(iss,name,',');
106         std::getline(iss,status,',');
107         std::getline(iss,email,',');
108         cout<<name<<endl;
109         Student newStudent(id,name,status,email);
110         Student::studentList.insert(std::pair<int,Student>(id,newStudent));
```

Above is the method I am defining. When the cout is executed the output is:

John Doe

Matt Smith

Before I added in the second getline(iss,name,',') the cout did nothing.

Can anyone explain why it works with the line repeated and why the same code won't work for status and email?

example line from file:

1,john doe,freshman,jd@email.com

EDIT:

I used std::ignore(1,',') before the first getline(iss,name,',') and received the error 'ignore' is undeclared in this namespace 'std'.

Comment: It would be easier if you also include the file format/layout.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone explain why it works with the line repeated and why the same code won't work for status and email?

Because your first operation on `isa` is `iss>>id`.

Presumably your input file is of the form `id,name,status,email`. That first operation reads up to but not including the first comma. That first comma is still in the input stream. This means your first `std::getline(iss,name,',')` reads all the stuff remaining before that first comma and that first comma. All the stuff remaining before that first comma -- that's an empty string.

It's best not to mix parsing concepts. Split the line along the commas, then parse each of those split elements.

**Edit**
Another way to deal with this issue: call `std::ignore` instead of that first call to `std::getline`. The next character to be read should be a comma, so just ignore it. This is okay if you can assume a properly formatted input file. It is not okay if you have to deal with the vagaries of input files created by humans.

Another issue: Suppose someone's name is "John Doe, PhD" or the email address is "John Doe, PhD "?

**Edit 2**
Just to clarify, suppose the line contains "1234,John Doe,freshman,jdoe@college_name.edu".

Input pointer prior to `iss>>id`:
`1234,John Doe,freshman,jdoe@college_name.edu`
`^`
The call to `iss>>id` sets `id` to 1234 and advances the input pointer to the first non-numeric character -- the first comma.

Input pointer after `iss>>id` (prior to first call to `std::getline`):
`1234,John Doe,freshman,jdoe@college_name.edu`
`____^`
The first `std::getline(iss,name,',')` sees the input pointer is at a comma. It sets `name` to the empty string and advances the input pointer to just after the comma.

Input pointer after first call to `std::getline` (prior to second call to `std::getline`):
`1234,John Doe,freshman,jdoe@college_name.edu`
`_____^`
The second `std::getline(iss,name,',')` reads up to the second comma. It sets `name` to "John Doe" empty string and advances the input pointer to just after the second comma.

Input pointer after second call to `std::getline` (prior to third call to `std::getline`):
`1234,John Doe,freshman,jdoe@college_name.edu`
`______________^`

Comment: _This means your first std::getline(iss,name,',') reads all the stuff remaining before that first comma and that first comma._ Actually, assuming the id field is valid (and therefore all read into the id variable), the first getline will return nothing. The comma is discarded.

Comment: *All the stuff remaining before that first comma* -- there is no such stuff. Another way to look at it: *All the stuff remaining before the first comma* is the empty string, which is exactly what I said in my answer.

Comment: _reads all the stuff remaining before that first comma and that first comma_ That's what I was referring to.

Comment: @computerfreaker - I think we're saying the same thing. The first `std::getline` doesn't get the name. Assuming a properly formatted input fie, it advances the stream pointer so that the next character to be read is the first character in the name.

Comment: Right. I think I misunderstood part of your answer, my bad.

Comment: Wow you explained that extremely well. I will try it tomorrow morning and report back so please don't forget about me:)

Comment: Also the format of he file is set and won't change from what you assumed it to be.

Comment: So I should use std::ignore for each calling of std::getline? Because if I use the getline(iss,status,',') twice I still get empty strings.

Comment: @DavidHammen I made a small edit trying out what you said and had an error  that I am not sure how to handle.